# What does it mean when a URL reports true for NSURLUbiquitousItemHasUnresolvedConflictsKey but there are no other versions of the URL?

Tags: icloud, uidocument, nsfileversion

In order to test conflicts, I've been saving two different versions of the same document on two devices.  On both devices I would then be able to look at the `currentVersionOfItemAtURL` to see the 'winning' version - which was the same on both devices - and the `otherVersionsOfItemAtURL` or `removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL` to see the others.

However I now seem  to have got a document in a weird state, where `currentVersionOfItemAtURL` is different on the two devices, and there are no `otherVersionsOfItemAtURL` or `removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL`.  Using `getResourceValue:forKey:` with `NSURLUbiquitousItemHasUnresolvedConflictsKey` reports that the URL has unresolved conflicts, but I've no way of seeing them.

What does it mean when a URL reports true for NSURLUbiquitousItemHasUnresolvedConflictsKey but there are no other versions of the URL?  Is this a case I need to handle in a production app?

Comment: @Simon - did you figure it out ? can you add the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

I followed the Apple sample code for resolving conflicts, but discovered when testing on iOS8 with the (old) Documents and Data store (not iCloud Drive) that setting the `NSFileVersion` property `resolved = TRUE` was not sufficient. `setResolved` would sometimes fail.

The solution was to call `removeAndReturnError` on the result on `unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL`. The documentation says (my emphasis):
"For any versions you no longer need, call the `removeAndReturnError:` method of `NSFileVersion` to reclaim the storage for the file. Document revisions remain on the **server** until you delete them."

```
for (NSFileVersion *v in [NSFileVersion unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:conflictURL])
        if ([v removeAndReturnError:&error] == NO)
            MRLOGERROR(error);
```

This seems to have resolved that problem.

Note I wouldn't be concerned that `currentVersionOfItemAtURL` differed between devices. I understand it is essentially arbitrary and will depend on the order changes occurred on the device.

Also note that all the conflict resolution actions should be wrapped inside a file coordinator:

```
[[[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil]
 coordinateWritingItemAtURL:self.conflictFileName options:0 error:&coordError byAccessor:
 ^(NSURL *conflictURL) {
....
/// resolve conflicts here
....
}];
```